# PHP5.2.3 for debian etch?

Tags: debian, php5, debian-etch

Is it possible to get PHP5.2.3 for debian etch?

I got 5.2.0-8+etch13

Comment: Any particular reason why you want 5.2.3 specifically?

Comment: Yes. I want to run Kohana framework. It is a requirement (kohanaphp.com)

Comment: Seems as if the Kohana Requirements page say "PHP version >= 5.2.3". That is, you need 5.2.3, or newer.

Comment: Correct, I need 5.2.3 or newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly from official Debian repositories but you can 'backport' newer PHP packages yourself if really needed.

It requires a few development packages, a few packaging knowledge and time.

[Some people already did](http://hype.sourceforge.jp/f/dists/etch/backports/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Change your apt sources to fetch from unstable.

Comment: Actually, Debian unstable currently has PHP 5.2.11. The same goes for testing (squeeze).

Comment: Ok, based on new info, never mind I guess.